Should "and guess what" be in commas?

"It also sparks, and guess what?" (My example sentence.)

"After years of wearing holes into bodega linoleum, Mom and Dad retired, and guess what? They began spending the money they had locked away." Source

“People are lying on the sidewalks, and I’m like, why? People are begging for jobs and guess what, here’s your work force right here.” Source

"I watched a short demonstration and was inspired to look up kendo’s connection to Star Wars light sabers, and guess what, all you little boys who used to whack me with anything resembling a light saber in our youth, you know a little kendo." Source


When does "guess what" or "and guess what" need to be put in commas and when it doesn't? Are all these example sentences correct? Thanks.

They all look fine to me. I wouldn't think of needing commas, I would think of it as using them to assist readers by making the flow of the text clear as they read.

How do you justify omitting a comma after "jobs" in the third sentence?

I don't justify it either way. I simply ask myself, Does the sentence make sense as currently punctuated? If not, then I consider how and where a comma will help. Did you understand sentence #3 when you first read it? If yes, then it didn't need any further commas.

If I search for the sequence "and guess what said", most instances match the current context. Sometimes that final question is preceded by a comma (or a hyphen or a period), other times not. It's really just a stylistic orthographic choice that probably never makes any difference to how the reader "interprets" the text. But personally I'd probably start a new sentence by capitalizing And. But I think you need to end it with a question mark after ...what? (maybe exclamation mark! :), or it looks strange.

@Peter I don't know, if it's in the middle of a sentence, to me, it seems like the comma is pretty much necessary to "break the flow" because usually this phrase stands out in a speech. Similarly, when someone ends a sentence with a tag question, we need a comma. I don't think the rules are so "loose" as you make them here.

I guess you're welcome to your opinion, since I'm saying it's a matter of personal choice. But I'm a native Anglophone with a degree in English who's read thousands of books over a lifetime, whereas you're presumably a "learner". And imho some opinions are worth more than others in such contexts. Bear in mind these "interruptive questions" can only really occur orthographically in the context of informal speech, where "rules" are inherently very loose anyway.

The first one doesn't make any sense to me. It needs to be followed by something. But yeah you can punctuate the others like that; I'm sure there are similar questions but I've no idea how to search for them.

The commas are used to avoid "garden path" parsing of the sentences. If you write

Mom and Dad retired and guess what?

it initially seems like "and" will introduce a second action that Mom and Dad performed, as in

Mom and Dad retired and moved to Florida.

But "guess what?" is an independent clause, and the comma sets it apart from the first clause.
When speaking this sentence there would probably be a slight pause before "and", which serves a similar purpose. The listener will detect that "retired" is the end of an utterance.

Why "and guess what" is an independent clause?

Because it's a different thought -- it's an idiom for "and here's what happened next"
